# Calling delphi 2006 dll with a pchar parameter from delphiXE

Tags: delphi, dll, unicode, char, delphi-xe

Since I've upgraded from delphi 5 to XE I'm struggling to use specific Dlls that were compiled a while ago. My blocking point seems related to the unicode/ansi character but I haven't found out how to solve the problem

Here is an example of procedure:

```
procedure GetFilename(Buffer: PChar; BufSize: Integer); stdcall;
```

In my code I'm calling this that way

```
implementation    
procedure GetFilename; external 'myDll.dll' name 'GetFilename';
procedure myproc
var
  buffer : Array [0..255] of Char;
begin
  GetFilename(buffer, length(buffer)-1);
  Showmessage(buffer); //This gives me chinese character
end;
```

Buffer contains this:

```
byte((@buffer[0])^); // 67 which is the ASCII for C
byte((@buffer[1])^); // 92 which is the ASCII for \
```

what I'm expecting normal is a string starting with "C:\"

Has anyone faced the same problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because the dll was made using a non-Unicode version of Delphi  you must change the declaration from

```
procedure GetFilename(Buffer: PChar; BufSize: Integer); stdcall;
```

to

```
procedure GetFilename(Buffer: PAnsiChar; BufSize: Integer); stdcall;
```

and the buffer variable from

```
buffer : Array [0..255] of Char;
```

to

```
buffer : Array [0..255] of AnsiChar;
```

Additionally to learn about the Delphi Unicode support take a look to the [`Delphi and Unicode`](http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/images/38980/Delphi_and_Unicode.pdf) Whitepaper from Marco Cantú.

Comment: No need to change the `external` declaration of `GetFilename` in the implementation section. Only the declaration in the interface section must be changed from `PChar` to `PAnsiChar`.